# How to build a django queryset in order to show all related objects grouped and show in the render template

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Achieve: Show the data into the template as example bellow:

```
PLan 1: ABC
 - General Objective 1
     - Sub-Objective-1
       - Task 1
       - Task 2
     - Sub-Objective-2
       - Task 1
PLan 2: ZZZ
 - General Objetivo General 1
     - Sub-Objetivo-1
       - Tarea 1
PLan 3: DDD
 - General Objetivo General 1
     - Sub-Objetivo-1
       - Tarea 1
     - Sub-Objetivo-2
       - Tarea 1
```

This means that: A plan can have many general objectives and this general objective can have several sub-objectives and each of its objectives can have one or several tasks.

My actual models and all relations:

```
class PlanObjective(models.Model):
    actionplan = models.ForeignKey(ActionPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    center = models.ForeignKey(Center, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    centerobjective = models.ForeignKey(CenterObjective, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=False, default='')

class PlanSubObjective (models.Model):
    actionplan = models.ForeignKey(ActionPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    center = models.ForeignKey(Center, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    planobjective = models.ForeignKey(PlanObjective, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=False, default='')


class PlanSubObjectiveTask (models.Model):
    actionplan = models.ForeignKey(ActionPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    center = models.ForeignKey(Center, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    planobjective = models.ForeignKey(PlanObjective, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    plansubobjective = models.ForeignKey(PlanSubObjective, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_complete = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True, default='0')
```

This is my actual query:

```
plans = PlanSubObjectiveTask.objects.filter(period=period).select_related(
        'plansubobjective', 'planobjective', 'actionplan')
```

I was reading the following documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup but the results are not the expected.

If you considered that exist a best way to build the queryset is complete welcome.

I really need a help to complete this task.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, why do you have such tables? Both `PlanSubObjective` and `PlanSubObjectiveTask` have a fk to `PlanObjective`. Is it some sort of optimization to avoid joins because of critical performance? I'd advice to consider normalization first. A chain `ActionPlan --> [PlanObjective --> [PlanSubObjective --> [PlanSubObjectiveTask]]]` requires 3 fk's, not 6 (`[]` represent "Many" side)

Comment: Thanks @SUTerliakov, First I updated the models in the question I had a mistake when I wrote it.
I'm new on this and do not have any particular optimization to avoind joins, was my way to create realation between models.
Is true that an ActionPlan can have many PlanObjective, PlanSubObjective and PlanSubObjectiveTask due to each end of year each plan need to be duplicate. passing ActionPlan with all relational record as a new record
 
I really apreciate from your experience what is the best way to normaize this and how I can find my achive. 
Thanks.